# Custom camera in iOS like Snapchat

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, snapchat

How does Snapchat make a custom UI for the camera, and how do they put a blur over it? I tried to accomplish the blur by putting a BlurView on top of the ImageView that I make into the camera with UIImagePicker, in

```
override func viewWillAppear(bool {
super.viewWillAppear(true)
'UIImagePicker logic'
}
```

But the imagepicker is not working until I remove the BlurView from the super view

[image: CustomUI]
[image: Blur]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImagePicker will not work in this situation. Have to use AVFoundation and CALayer. This allows me to make a custom camera with a custom UI, and custom functionality.  [See this tutorial for basic introduction](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/taking-control-of-the-iphone-camera-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/)